# c# "\xC0\x80" sent as C0 3f ... Odd problem cant figure out the solution

Tags: c#

I have a very interesting problem. One to which i have yet to be able to find an answer.
the code as follows

```
Console.WriteLine("\xc0\x80");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new byte[] { 0xC0, 0x80 }));
Console.WriteLine( Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("\xc0\x80")));

byte[] bt = new byte[2];
bt[0] = (byte)'\xC0';
bt[1] = (byte)'\x80';
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bt));
```

produces the following output:

```
À?
À€
À?
À€
```

when encoded to bytes using codepage 1252 "\xc0\x80" produces C0 3f ..

however, if i cast it straight to a byte array, the bytes are C0 80

Suggestions?

Also, the same code ran from vs in another machine, produces À€ on every line...
The problem isent so much the code page, it's got to be a setting in vs or in windows
causing the lookup from my default codepage to 1252.

Comment: I wonder how you cast a string to a byte array.

Comment: @Darin: By using Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(str).  Of course, this isn't a cast, but I assume it is what he meant.

Comment: @yodaj007, this is not casting, this is converting using encoding. I ask about the second method that the OP describes where he says I quote: `if i cast it straight to a byte array, the bytes are C0 80`. I was just curious about this *casting* as it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Darin:  See the second sentence of my comment.  Of course I know it isn't a cast.

Comment: @yodaj007, in his question the OP describes two different methods of converting a string to a byte array which yield different results. The first method is more than clear it is exactly what you describe in your comment. It is the second method I am asking about, because usually when you ask why you get two different results using two different methods it is necessary to describe the two methods.

Answer (score 4):

3f is a question mark. It is produced because CP 1252 does not support the character U+0080 (which is a control character); in CP 1252, byte 80 is U+20AC (EURO SIGN).

If you want a EURO SIGN in the 1252 string, put it also into the `str` variable (e.g. as \u20ac).

**Edit**: Going to your examples one by one:

```
Console.WriteLine("\xc0\x80");
```

Your terminal doesn't support the character \x80 (PAD - Padding character), so it prints a question mark.

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).
  GetString(new byte[] { 0xC0, 0x80 }));
```

The GetString call gives you "\xc0\u20ac". Encoding this to the terminal's character set gives the EURO SIGN.

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(
       Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("\xc0\x80")));
```

GetBytes gives you { 0xC0, 0x3f}. GetString then gives you "\xC0?", and that gets printed.

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bt));
```

This is really the same code as the second example.

Comment: This is correct, however, the cast from the character \x80 to a byte does not produce the same as the encoding from "\x80" on MY machine, the same code, ran on another machine DOES. After my code is compiled to IL i really could care less because IL handles the locale with the encoding class.

Comment: See my edit; I've explained the specific output. Notice that you never ever "cast from the character \x80" in your code. That character doesn't show up at all (except as part of a string) - only a byte 0x80 shows up, but that is not a character (it's a byte). char != byte